# How to test if a player is wearing a helmet in 1.16?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make a Minecraft server and I want to test if a player is wearing a helmet named GOD SWORD (yes I meant helmet, I thought a helmet called god sword would be funny). Anyway, after hours of trial and error I still can't figure this out. Please help! My version is 1.16.

Comment: When you say "trial and error", do you mean you were trying things blindly without knowing what you were doing? We can't help people who haven't tried to help themselves —have you at least tried looking up some tutorials?

Comment: Maybe theres a way to use the replaceitem command to test? Im not able to use my pc rn but will test and see if i can get it to work

Comment: Can you give us the helmet nbt?  You can do that by holding the helmet in your main hand and running the following command in chat.  `/data get entity @s SelectedItem`.  That should give you the nbt, and then you can edit your answer to add the nbt.